# jQuery working on computer but doesnt on iPad?

Tags: jquery, ipad

following code:

```
           if(!$($texte).parent().hasClass('text-bg'))
                $texte = $($texte).parent();
            if($($texte).hasClass('text-left')){
                flag = $texte.data('animToggle');
                $texte.data('animToggle', !flag);
                $texte.animate({
                    'left': flag ? '-48%' : '0'
                })
            }

            if($($texte).hasClass('text-right')){
                flag = $texte.data('animToggle');
                $texte.data('animToggle', !flag);
                $texte.animate({
                    'right': flag ? '-48%' : '0'
                })
            }
```

Everything is working just fine on computer. The problem is the following: On my iPad the left animation works flawlessly, but the right animation bugs. When I first click on it, it just jumps out. On the second click to make the div animate to the right again, it animates just fine. The CSS of these is just for the left one: `position:absolute; left:-48%;` and for the right just switched `right:-48%`.

So what am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance

http://jsfiddle.net/46bu6orf/

!Update:! The solution of TrueBlueAussie in combination with a change by me works now:

```
$(document).on('click', function (event) {
    var $texte = $(event.target);

    // Find the closest sliding container to the item clicked (match either class)
    var $bar = $texte.closest('.text-right, .text-left');

    // Get the animation open/closed flag
    var flag = $bar.data('animToggle');

    // toggle the animation flag and store it
    $bar.data('animToggle', !flag);

    // If this is a left bar animate left edge
    if ($bar.hasClass('text-left')) {
        flag ? $bar.css('left', '-52%') : $bar.css('left','0');
    // Reverse flag for left to show correct < >
    flag = !flag;
    }

    // If this is a right bar animate right edge
    if ($bar.hasClass('text-right')) {
        flag ? $bar.css('right', '-52%') : $bar.css('right','0');
    }

    // Toggle the < > display
    var $span = $bar.find('.pfeil');
    $span.html(flag ? '<' : '>');
});
```

It seems that .animate 'right' property has a bug on the iPad. By using jQuery's `.css` and adding `transition` to the container, it works.

Comment: Could you provide a working jsfiddle so that we may compare?

Comment: You have a lot of code that seems to be doing nothing in the example, a lot of error checks for child lengths that will always be true (almost every single `if` should be checking `length`). Also a simple `var $texte = $(event.target);` as the first line will remove the need for `$($texte)` everywhere. *I suggest you cleanup and comment your code as the issue you mention may just be a side-effect of another problem.* :)

Comment: Followup: When I correct some of the errors mentioned (the incorrect `if` checks for instance), the code stops working as it did previously, which means the logic as written is incorrect but you would not know it. Please do comment your code so that the intention is clear.

Comment: Can you tell me how you mean your last comment? Because for me the code works fine, and your edited code works just as fine also?

Comment: Re last comment: `if($($texte).children('.text-left'))` will *always* return true as jQuery objects always exist, but it can have a zero length (which is what you need to check for).

Comment: +1: Thank you for the bounty. Almost feels like getting paid for it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the final answer, as more information is needed, but there is way too much information here for a comment. There were so many issues I did a complete re-write to simplify the code and understand what was going on.

I also modified the HTML and styling so that *both* a left and right panel are available at the same time.

Here is the result so far: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/46bu6orf/18/

```
$(document).on('click', function (event) {
    var $texte = $(event.target);

    // Find the closest sliding container to the item clicked (match either class)
    var $bar = $texte.closest('.text-right, .text-left');

    // Get the animation open/closed flag
    var flag = $bar.data('animToggle');

    // toggle the animation flag and store it
    $bar.data('animToggle', !flag);

    // If this is a left bar animate left edge
    if ($bar.hasClass('text-left')) {
        $bar.animate({
            'left': flag ? '-48%' : '0'
        })
        // Reverse flag for left to show correct < >
        flag = !flag;
    }

    // If this is a right bar animate right edge
    if ($bar.hasClass('text-right')) {
        $bar.animate({
            'right': flag ? '-48%' : '0'
        })
    }

    // Toggle the < > display based on the open/closed flag
    var $span = $bar.find('.pfeil');
    $span.html(flag ? '<' : '>');
});
```

This can all be simplified even further, but soon you would not recognize any of it :)

*Immediately I noticed the styling is not compatible with my iPhone, which indicates my iPad will fair no better. I will investigate later and update on my findings. I hope the above sample will at least provide a better starting point for others*

Comment: Hey, thank you for the answer. I noticed that my code had a problem, because when I clicked on the container, and not on the text or the arrow, the function wouldn't work. This code is much better already. Although it didn't solve the issue with the right animation. Have you seen, that the left animation works just fine, but on the right side it doesn't? Thank you again!

Comment: I got it to work!!!! It seems to be a problem with the .animate of jQuery. I changed .animate to .css and just changed the css left or right property and then I just added transition on my containers and it works! Thank you for your code, I learned much from this! If you want, you can add the css solution to your code, so I can mark it as right answer

Comment: @Frederik Witte: Feel free... Just glad you sorted it (and glad you liked the improvements) :)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing following css property, maybe this work and lemme know:

```
.text-bg {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #777;
    height: 500px;
    overflow: hidden; /*This will hide rest part of slider giving your page better look*/
    position: relative;
    width: 300px; /*add width maybe 100% or whichever you want*/
}
```

Note: i don't owe ipad, and i tried on simulator.

Please lemme know whether this worked or not

Comment: oh okay buddy, need to try and test on ipad itself, will let you know then.